Performance test between MySQL and MongoDB
I am a beginner in the field of databases and I need to compare the performance between MySQL and MongoDB. For this, I will insert 1 million records and then perform a join. I will measure the performance by looking at the time it takes both databases to perform these operations. The problem is that I am not sure how to proceed.
So far, I have installed MySQL and MongoDB on my computer and created three tables in MySQL (clients, products, sales) and three collections in MongoDB (clients, products, sales). Is this a good start? If so, how should I continue?
Example table client in MySQL:
CREATE TABLE clients (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

And so this is the structure of the coresponding collection in MongoDB:
{
    "_id": ObjectId,
    "name": String,
    "email": String
}


I doubt that comparing the performance between MySQL and MongoDB is useful as you describe it. Do you have already a performance problem with either and think that using the other would help? Then go ahead. But this looks like an academic problem here. Even if you have finished comparing, someone else will find ways to tweak your testing setup (introducing indexes and other stuff) so that one database system performs better.
